# Show that $U$ is both unitary and hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

If $u$ is a unit vector in $\mathbb{C}^n$, and $U=I-2uu^H$, show that $U$ is both unitary and hermitian and that therefore it is it's own inverse.

---

My attempt:

Since $u$ is a unit vector it's norm is 1 and therefore $u^Hu$=1

$$U=I-2uu^H$$
$$Uu=Iu-2uu^Hu$$
$$Uu=-u$$

So the implication is that $$U=-I$$

Then $\overline{-I}^T=-I$ so clearly $U$ is both hermitian and normal and it's own inverse.

Is this correct?

Comment: This is definitely not correct. Just because $Tv = -v$ for *one particular choice of* $v$ (!) does not mean that $T = -I$ in general. It would have to be the case that $Tv = -v$ for **any** $v$ to conclude that $T = -I$. To show it is unitary and Hermitian, why don't you try explicitly computing $U^H$? Note that a matrix is Hermitian if and only if $T = T^H$; likewise, a (square) matrix is unitary if and only if $T^H T = I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U^H = (I - 2uu^H)^H = I^H - (2uu^H)^H = I - 2(uu^H)^H = I - 2(u^H)^H(u^H) = I - 2uu^H = U$.

Now $U^HU = U^2 = (I - 2uu^H)^2 = I^2 - 4uu^H + 4(uu^H)^2$

$= I - 4uu^H + 4uu^Huu^H = I - 4uu^H + 4u(u^Hu)u^H = I - 4uu^H + 4uu^H = I$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A:= uu^H$ so that $$ A:=(a_{ij}),\ a_{ij}=u_i\overline{u}_j =\overline{a}_{ji} $$

Hence $$ A=A^H,\ U=U^H $$

and since $AA^H=A$, $$ UU^H=UU=I $$

[add] If $\mathbb{C}^n$ has an inner product $$ (v,w)=\sum v_i\overline{w}_i $$
 then $$ Uv=v-2(v,u)u $$ That is $U$ is a reflection wrt a hyperplane $u^\perp$. So $U^2=I$.